# Does _MSC_VER depend on toolkit version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a Ruby C Extension against Ruby libs that where compiled with Visual Studio 2010. (I cannot change this, or recompile the Ruby core I'm building against, because it's embedded in a third party application.)

My project started out in Visual Studio 2010, but I later started using Visual Studio 2013 without upgrading the project - so it's still using the VS2010 toolkit.

In the Ruby include headers that I need to use there is a check:

```
#if _MSC_VER != 1600
#error MSC version unmatch: _MSC_VER: 1600 is expected.
#endif
```

Now, I thought since I was using the VS2010 toolkit for my project this check would still pass in VS2013. And this is where I'm confused:

The solution builds and creates the `.so` file which works, there is no warnings or errors in Output, but I just discovered that the Error List displayed a warning. IntelliSense will display `1800` for `_MSC_VER` - yet it compiles.

```
1   IntelliSense: #error directive: MSC version unmatch: _MSC_VER: 1600 is expected.    c:\Users\Thomas\Documents\subd\ThirdParty\include\ruby\win32\i386-mswin32_100\ruby\config.h 4
```

[image: MSC version unmatch: _MSC_VER: 1600 is expected]

So what is going on here?

Isn't Visual Studio using the VS2010 compiler when my toolkit is set to `v100`? (Then I'd expect `_MSC_VER` to be `1600`.)

Is the `#warning` directive not something that blocks the compiler?

Is it IntelliSense that isn't picking up the toolkit version and instead always assume `_MSC_VER` is `1800`?

Comment: As far as I know VS2010 didn't have the same Intellisense engine that VS2012 and later did so I guess it's using VS2013 for *parsing*.

Comment: So it's an IntelliSense bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_MSC_VER is directly tied to a toolkit, not the IDE.

The buggy Intelisense also behaves the same in VS2012 (with Vs2010 toolkit)...

Comment: That's what I wanted to confirm - didn't want to ignore a real error. I'll report the bug is see if it perhaps gets fixed.